# Jersey fluent API troubles

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, fluent-interface, jersey-client

I'm rewriting some code because I had to upgrade to the latest version of Jersey (2.18) and I don't understand why the fluent API is working the way it does.

Why does this compile:

```
Response.Status.Family responseFamily = webTarget
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE))
    .getStatusInfo()
    .getFamily();
```

But this doesn't:

```
Response response = webTarget
    .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

response.getStatusInfo().getFamily();  // the method getStatusInfo() isn't available here; why not?
```

For reference, here's my whole method that used to work fine in Jersey 2.5.1 but won't even compile in 2.18 because of the getStatusInfo() method:

```
public void postGenericJson(Object entity, String... pathSegments) {
    Response response;
    WebTarget webTarget = httpsClient.target(apiBaseUrl);

    try {
        for (String pathSegment : pathSegments) {
            webTarget = webTarget.path(pathSegment);
        }

        response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(Entity.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

        log.trace("Issued POST to '" + webTarget.getUri().toString() + "'.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error posting DTO: POST " + webTarget.getUri().toString(), e);
        throw new RuntimeException("Error posting DTO.");
    }

    if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL) {
        throw new ResponseProcessingException(response, "Error POSTing DTO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a Maven issue.  I had my own dependency for jersey-server and jersey-client, both at version 2.18, but another dependency had its own dependency on jersey-1.9.1.  I thought I had excluded them, but they were in my library list anyway.  I finally realized I had used the wrong package name in my exclusion.  I changed the excluded groupId to `com.sun.jersey` from `org.glassfish.jersey.core` and now my code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

As I found in the jersey API it is not response that returns the status info, but it should rather be `Response.StatusType`, the same should apply to the getFamily.

See jersey api, pleach do search for Response.class
https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/index.html